# Get localStorage data and send by Crossdomain with Porthole js

Tags: jquery, iframe, local-storage

I'm doing a online code editor like dabblet with the option of add bootstrap or only normalize to help the user, and I use **localStorage** to return the code when they refresh the page also keep the option they selected.

[JS Code](https://github.com/thinkxl/docss/blob/master/js/app.js), [Live Demo](http://thinkxl.github.com/docss/)

I'm using iframe crossdomain comunication with PortholeJS to do that.

When the user type code, the .val() of this is saved on localStorage, so when the user refresh the page i want to get the code from localStorage and saving on a var, then showing on the editors again and send a post with PortholeJS to the iframe, but when I refresh only can get the code back, but I don't get the results on the iframe

```
    getLocalStorageData: function(){
        cssMSG = "/* Do your CSS here! */";
        htmlMSG = "<!-- Do your HTML here! -->";

        // If the localStorage is empty then set the default msgs
        if (!localStorage.getItem('cssDB')) { localStorage.setItem('cssDB', cssMSG); }
        if (!localStorage.getItem('htmlDB')) { localStorage.setItem('htmlDB', htmlMSG); }

        // Save the data on a object
        getCSSData = localStorage.getItem('cssDB');
        getHTMLData = localStorage.getItem('htmlDB');

        // Send the data to the code editors
        docss.setValue(getCSSData);
        dohtml.setValue(getHTMLData);

        // Set an option like overflow-x: break-word on the code editors
        dohtml.session.setUseWrapMode(true);
        docss.session.setUseWrapMode(true);

        // This send the data to the iframe from the code editors when load the page
        windowProxy.post({'html' : getHTMLData });
        windowProxy.post({'css' : getCSSData });
    },
```

Sorry for my bad english